# Arrays.setAll wont work with boolean

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, boolean

I want to create a big array, and want to try out some lambda, but for some reason that:

```
cells = new boolean[this.collums][this.rows];
IntStream.range(0, cells.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(cells[x], e -> MathX.fastNextInt(1) == 0 ? true : false));
```

wont work, even that:

```
cells = new boolean[this.collums][this.rows];
IntStream.range(0, cells.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(cells[x], e -> true));
```

dose not work.

The compiler error is :

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to T

and:

> The method setAll(T[], IntFunction) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (boolean[], ( e) -> {})

Comment: `MathX.fastNextInt(1) == 0 ? true : false` can be simplified to just `MathX.fastNextInt(1) == 0`

Comment: @SeanBright what is `MathX` anyway?

Comment: @nullpointer, no clue.

Comment: MathX is just my Math functions like Math expandet.

Comment: @TheSorm If you specifically need to stick to `boolean[][]` implementation, you can use [Arrays.fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46199616/1746118) as well.

Comment: Can't you use [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)? It would be ideal for this...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it should be reference type: `Boolean`:

```
Boolean[][] cells = new Boolean[this.collums][this.rows];
```

---

**UPD:** if you want to use `boolean` type, you have to write your own implementation of `setAll()` for primitive boolean type:

```
interface BooleanUnaryOperator {
    boolean apply(int x);
}

public static void setAll(boolean[] array, BooleanUnaryOperator generator) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = generator.apply(i);
}
```

**UPD-2**: As [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) mentioned, the name `BooleanUnaryOperator` is misleading, and it is better to use the existent class for this purpose - [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/IntPredicate.html). (In this case change `array[i] = generator.apply(i);` to `array[i] = generator.test(i);`)

Comment: And there is no way with the boolean type? I can not use Boolean because ther array is pretty big and i need to work fast on that and create it fast.

Comment: @TheSorm *the array is pretty big and i need to work fast on that and create it fast* and how is the primitve vs reference hindering in there?

Comment: @nullpointer I tryed it out and to use Boolean is by crating a 10000 +10000 Array 2 to 10 times slower.

Comment: @TheSorm of course it will be slower because of autoboxing boolean values. Just as a hint, try to replace  `e -> true` with `Boolean.TRUE` (and `false` with `Boolean.FALSE` respectively) - when dealing with `Boolean[][]`  type

Comment: `BooleanUnaryOperator` is a misleading name as it would imply a `(boolean) -> boolean` signature. The correct name following the `java.util.function` scheme would be either `IntToBooleanFunction` or `IntPredicate`. The latter even [does exist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/IntPredicate.html)…

Comment: Thank you @Holger for pointing out me this, I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way of setting all the values to `true` would be using **[`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-boolean:A-boolean-)** with an iteration over one dimension as:

```
cells = new boolean[this.collums][this.rows];
for (boolean[] cell : cells) {
    Arrays.fill(cell, true);
}
```

---

In case `setAll` is the only option, you would have to use the Reference type `Boolean` in your code as:

```
Boolean [][] cells = new Boolean[10][10];
IntStream.range(0, cells.length).forEach(x -> Arrays.setAll(cells[x], e -> true));
```

Since the [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does not have an existing implementation of `setAll` for a `boolean[]`  and it ends up consuming [`setAll(T[] array,IntFunction<? extends T> generator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) which requires a reference type. Also note worthy a point, you can create your custom `setAll` method using `boolean` as suggested by [@Andremoniy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198843/1746118).